# Leer los datos de un string obtenido de una api con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-6

Estoy consumiento la api de la url https://mindicador.cl/api/uf donde obtengo los valores de la unidad de fomento de mi pais y los estoy realizando de la siguiente manera

En mi archivo web tengo lo siguiente

```
Route::get('getIndicators', function()
{
    $api = 'https://mindicador.cl/api/uf';
    if ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
        $json = file_get_contents($api);
    } else {
        $curl = curl_init($api);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    }
    return $json;
});
```

y esto me resulta lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revisando y haciendo un var_dump al $json obtenido me arroja lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que quiero hacer es poder acceder a las "serie" que contiene los valores de la unidad de fomento y las fechas pero no logro hacerlo. 
Estoy intentando lo siguiente.

```
foreach ($json->serie as $uf ) {
    echo $uf;
}
```

y me arroja el mensaje:

> ErrorException
>   Trying to get property 'serie' of non-object

Comment: Tenes que especificar el valor que queres imprimir.
echo $uf->valor;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes decodificar el JSON primero para que sea una variable PHP:

```
$result = json_decode($json);

foreach ($result->serie as $uf) {
    echo $uf; // Esto no creo que funcione como lo deseas

    echo $uf->valor;
}
```

Revisa la documentación de PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Gracias compañero es justamente lo que buscaba hacer